# Styling third last element in LI tag?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

```
<ul class="pager">
  <li class="first"><span>1</span></li>
  <li><a href="/blog?page=2">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="/blog?page=3">3</a></li>
  <li><a href="/blog?page=4">4</a></li>
  <li><span>...</span></li>
  <li><a href="/blog?page=2">></a></li>
  <li class="last"><a href="/blog?page=8">>></a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to add style `background-color:white` to third last element of `<li>`.I dont know how many `<li>` will be there.The only thing I know is,I need to add style for third last `<li>`, is this possible in pure css?

Comment: Is it possible to do it with jquery?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you can use [`nth-last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-last-child)...

```
ul.pager li:nth-last-child(3)
{
    background-color:white;
}
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/dL882/)

[Browser support chart](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3)

Answer (score 0):

## :nth-clast-child()

```
ul.pager li:nth-last-child(3) {
    /* your style here */
    background-color: white;
}
```

View the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TSUV8/).

### Browser Support

> The :nth-last-child() selector is supported in all major browsers, except IE8 and earlier.

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-last-child.asp